# Problems with Bash 4.2.45 on Ubuntu

Tags: linux, macos, ubuntu, bash

I am using a remot server running Ubuntu 13.10 with Bash 4.2.45 installed. My home system is OS X Mavericks with Bash 3.2.51 (Darwin build) installed. I haven't used bash much in the past but I've been working on a pretty big script and noticed a few things that were weird about the version installed on the remote server.

Take a simple script for example:

```
#!/bin/sh

read n

if ((n > 10)); then
        echo "Number is pretty big"
else
        echo "NUMBER IS WEAK AND SMALL"
fi
```

While under bash 3.2.51 it recognizes the expression and works under the bash 4 on Ubuntu it throws a weird error:

```
script.sh: 5: script.sh: n: not found
```

But not only are (( . . . )) not recognized but sometimes variables and other logical statements. As a bash beginner it's very confusing and I wanted to ask what I could do about that. Can I change the syntax rules? Or just downgrade the remote server to a 3.x.y version?
Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When i've read your query i was surprised by the behaviour you have, so i've decided to reproduce it quickly, so i've setup a new Ubuntu 13.10 VM with Bash version 4.2.45.

Once done, i was able to reproduce the behaviour you describe.

After further investigations, it seems that you just have to replace **`#!/bin/sh`** by **`#!/bin/bash`** to make it works.

**Edit :**

To launch the script :

- **`bash script.sh`** and **`./script.sh`** will work.
- **`sh script.sh`** will not work.

Assuming you have **`#!/bin/bash`** at first line

Hope it will work for you !

Comment: Ah, I tried it with #!/bin/sh and #!/bin/bash. And on the remote desktop with 4.2.45 it both times throws the same errors. Are you sure that you're not changing anything else?

Comment: I have an OSX near me, will check why it works on it !

Comment: Like user2196728, I simply changed `#!/bin/sh` to `#!/bin/bash`, and the problem went away. `sh` is implemented as `dash` on Ubuntu and as `sh` on OSX - try doing a `man sh` on Ubuntu and on OSX.  On OSX, the man pages for `bash` and `sh` are combined, and the object file sizes of `bash` and `sh` on OSX are almost identical.  So, that leads me to believe that `sh` on Ubuntu has a different lineage than `bash`, especially since the sizes on Ubuntu are over 10% different.  I think proper `sh` scripts will run in `bash`, but not the other way around.

Answer (score 2):

### You aren't using the Bourne Again Shell at all.

It's a mistake to assume that `/bin/sh` is anything more than a POSIX-conformant shell.  (Even if it *were* bash, when bash is invoked as `sh` it subtly changes its behaviour.)  On Ubuntu, `/bin/sh` now defaults to the Debian Almquist Shell, which is a *different shell* — one of the many shells (Thompson, Bourne, Bourne Again, Almquist, Korn, Z, Friendly Interactive, C, Tenex C, BusyBox, Policy-compliant Ordinary, …) that one can find on Unix and Linux systems.  The switch of `/bin/sh` from Bourne Again to Debian Almquist improved the boot speed of Debian and Ubuntu systems, which execute a *lot* of shell scripts as part of the boot process.

If you really want to make use of *bashisms* like `((`…`))` in your script, then explicitly set `/bin/bash` as the script interpreter in its `#!` line.

Conversely, if you want to specify `/bin/sh` as your script interpreter across systems as diverse as Mac OS and Linux then stick strictly to only that which is POSIX-conformant.

### Further reading

- *[dash as `/bin/sh`](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DashAsBinSh)*.  Ubuntu wiki.
- *[dash as `/bin/sh`](https://wiki.debian.org/DashAsBinSh)*.  Debian wiki.
- "[6.11 bash POSIX mode](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Bash-POSIX-Mode)".  *Bash Reference manaual*.  GNU Project.
- *[bashisms](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/Bashism)*.  Greg's wiki.
- *[Shell Command Language](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/idx/shell.html)*.  IEEE Std 1003.1.  Issue 7.  The Open Group.

Comment: "As a bash beginner" Honestly no idea what you are trying to tell me…except yes, I should put bash in the header. Which I actually did on my linux script. But as somebody else pointed out, I need to run a bash script with "bash" (which I didn't know).

Answer (score 0):

`n` is a variable, so you need to reference it using a "$":

```
#!/bin/sh

read n

if (($n > 10)); then
        echo "Number is pretty big"
else
        echo "NUMBER IS WEAK AND SMALL"
fi
```

Comment: Althought yes that is true, it doesn't solve the problem. Well...it 
script.sh: 5: script.sh: 5: not found

Comment: Really? That works for me: https://p.6core.net/p/T0NVAIEcfAxVKcstThwCwD59

Comment: Right the issue isn't the 3.x darwin build. That's where everything works. It's the 4.x build on ubuntu that doesn't work

Comment: Right, with Bash 4.2.45 neither `n` nor `$n` was working with the initial given script

Comment: As was pointed out in more than one answer now, #!/bin/sh on Ubuntu is _not_ bash. (( )) is bash specific, so replace your hashbang: https://p.6core.net/p/k02MtdUYABC9pbXKjerrYjmi and it will work.

Comment: My point exactly...