# Different /bin/sh for a specific user

Tags: linux, bash, unix

I am running an Ubuntu distro where `/bin/sh` is a symlink to `/bin/dash`. While this is OK for most of my users, one of them must have `bin/sh` "symlinked" to `/bin/bash`.

Is that possible? I am not sure how to do this.

Regards.

Answer (score 3):

> […] one of them must have `/bin/sh` symlinked to `/bin/bash`.

I suspect that the actual state of affairs is:

> […] one of them has some badly written shell scripts with Bashisms in, and doesn't want to fix xyr bad scripts.

You cannot do a per-user symbolic link, obviously.  So get your user to get those Bashisms out of any shell script that uses `/bin/sh` as its interpreter, and to put `/bin/bash` (or the alternatives mentioned by piernov) in any shell scripts where the Bourne Again shell really is supposed to be the script interpreter.

These scripts, if they assume that `sh` is only ever the Bourne Again shell or if they rely upon Bashisms and don't in fact invoke the Bourne Again shell as `bash` (Even invoking it as `sh` is wrong if one wants some of a fair number number of Bashisms.), are *broken* and should be mended.

### Further reading

- https://superuser.com/a/696310/38062
- *[dash as `/bin/sh`](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DashAsBinSh)*.  Ubuntu wiki.
- *[dash as `/bin/sh`](https://wiki.debian.org/DashAsBinSh)*.  Debian wiki.
- *[bashisms](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/Bashism)*.  Greg's wiki.
- *[Shell Command Language](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/idx/shell.html)*.  IEEE Std 1003.1.  Issue 7.  The Open Group.

Answer (score 2):

`/bin/sh` is just a Bourne shell. Both dash and bash can act as sh-compatible shells, and since original Bourne shell isn't used anymore, sh is often a symlink to bash or dash (mainly on Ubuntu), or even zsh.

When using sh though, you shouldn't be using any specificity of a particular shell. That's why a script with a `#!/bin/sh` shebang shouldn't rely on any bashism for example. When it is using any particularity of bash, it should be using `#!/usr/bin/env bash`. That is for a shell used to run scripts.

Another aspect of shell is the command prompt used by an user. Most of the time it is defined in `/etc/passwd`, and the choice is at the discretion of the distribution you're using. If the default is to use dash, you can obviously change the line in `/etc/passwd` for a specific user and put `/usr/bin/bash`.

Finally, even if it's not a good idea, if you really want the `sh` command to run `bash`, if it's in a shell you should be able to `alias` it, or create a symlink to it in another directory (`~/bin` for example) then prepend it to the PATH (`export PATH="~/bin:${PATH}"`).

Comment: More accurately, `/bin/sh` is usually not the Bourne shell itself, but a link to another shell which adheres to the POSIX specification, which itself is based on but not identical to the original Bourne shell.